# Terraform : Getting AWS subnetID's for a given vpc failing, no results

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am working on creating an ElasticSearch cluster using Terraform. I am not able to get the subnet-ids for a given VPC, with aws_subnet_ids. The return is always null. What am I doing wrong?

Code :

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "eu-central-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "${pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")}"
}


variable "domain" {
  default = "tf-test"
}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  tags = {
    Name = var.vpc
  }
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "selected" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.selected.id}"
}

resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name           = "${var.domain}"
  elasticsearch_version = "6.3"

  cluster_config {
    instance_type = "m4.large.elasticsearch"
  }

  vpc_options {
    subnet_ids = [
      "${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids[0]}",
      "${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids[1]}",
    ]
  }
```

Output :

```
terraform plan :


  on main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es":
  55:       "${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids[0]}",

This value does not have any indices.


Error: Invalid index

  on main.tf line 56, in resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es":
  56:       "${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids[1]}",

This value does not have any indices.
```

**Update**

If I print the subnet id's without index, I am getting them :

[image]

Solved :

```
  subnet_id = "${element(module.vpc.public_subnets, 0)}"
```

VPC created in this manner :

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.6.0"

  name                 = var.vpc_name
  cidr                 = var.vpc_cidr
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = [var.public_subnet_1, var.public_subnet_2, var.public_subnet_3]
  public_subnets       = [var.private_subnet_1, var.private_subnet_2, var.private_subnet_3]
  enable_nat_gateway   = var.enable_nat_gateway
  single_nat_gateway   = var.single_nat_gateway
  enable_dns_hostnames = var.enable_dns_hostname

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                      = "1"
    "name" = var.public_subnet_name
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"             = "1"
    "name" = var.private_subnet_name

  }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `aws_elasticsearch_domain` and output `data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids` what do you see?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR   on main.tf line 44, in output "ids":
  44:   value = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids[0]}"

This value does not have any indices.

Comment: But I have the VPC and subnet.... I can see them in AWS...region is also correct.

Comment: That's not what I asked for. What is the output without the index?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR : Image added in main post, please check. :-)

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I have exactly the same issue

Comment: @Leo : Main post updated to reflect the answer. :-)